# mdPanel not updating array

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Using the sample of Angular Material about mdPanel as source ([Sample](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/panel)) I have a question that would resolve my problem

If after open the panel I update the 'desserts' array this new item is not showing in the panel. What should I do to make this new item showing in 'real-time' in the panel?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample with your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I had to create a DialogController and pass all arrays with the data to this controller once the arrays were filled.